# Server name not found in Kerberos database error?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, cloudera, hue

I install hue from github

In hue.ini file i set these parameters to connect hive

```
[desktop]
server_user=spnego
server_group=spnego
default_user=hue
.
.
.
[[kerberos]]
hue_keytab=/etc/spnego.keytab
# Kerberos principal name for Hue hue_principal=spnego/hostname.foo.com
# Frequency in seconds with which Hue will renew its keytab
REINIT_FREQUENCY=3600
# Path to keep Kerberos credentials cached
ccache_path=/tmp/hue_krb5_ccache
# Path to kinit
kinit_path=/path/to/kinit
krb5_renewlifetime_enabled=true

[hadoop]

# Configuration for HDFS NameNode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[hdfs_clusters]]
  # HA support by using HttpFs

[[[default]]]
# Enter the filesystem uri
fs_defaultfs=hdfs://mycluster

# NameNode logical name.
## logical_name=

# Use WebHdfs/HttpFs as the communication mechanism.
# Domain should be the NameNode or HttpFs host.
# Default port is 14000 for HttpFs.
webhdfs_url=http://mynamenode:50070/webhdfs/v1
#here when i set httpfs it says error unauthorized 401 even the service is up with kerberos i dont get it
# Change this if your HDFS cluster is Kerberos-secured
security_enabled=false

[beeswax]

# Host where HiveServer2 is running.
# If Kerberos security is enabled, use fully-qualified domain name (FQDN).
```

hive_server_host=hiveserver

```
# Binary thrift port for HiveServer2.
hive_server_port=10000

# Http thrift port for HiveServer2.
hive_server_http_port=10001
```

When i enter hue with **fake_user** its ok to get hdfs i see files ( fake_user is a user in hdfs)

But it gives error when i try to connect hive

The error : server not found in Kerberos database

So which server ? And in the logs there is no detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the keytab

I create the keytab for hive server with the proper values like hostname and principal

It works